# Javascript Regex replace not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, internet-explorer

The following JS works fine in FF, but doesn't replace anything in IE10:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('<span id=\"(.+?)\" class=\"questiontext\"><p(.*?)>(.+?)<\/p><\/span>', 'gim');
$('.questiontext_div').html(function(index, html) { return html.replace(pattern,'<span id="$1" class="questiontext"><legend>$3</legend></span>'); });
```

I am attempting to replace the p with a legend.

```
<div class="questiontext_div">
  <span id="C00B7205241531FD2BEF31301000101F0DESC" class="questiontext">
     <P style="font-weight: bold; color: #005881;">Text will go here!</P>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: **WHY!!!!???** You're using jquery. why regexes when jquery makes this sort of dom manipulation trivial?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would likely be simpler:

```
$('span.questiontext p').replaceWith('<legend...etc>');
```

and work on all browsers

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up using: $('span.questiontext p').replaceWith(function() {return '<legend>'+this.innerHTML+'</legend>' });